# Is there a quicker way to get a token's index from a doc?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, spacy

```
for token in doc:
   if token.text = 'is':
       print(token.i)
```

Given a token text, i.e. 'is', is there a faster way to get its index instead of iterating the token list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do faster with `numpy` array.

They say in the docstring:

> `def __iter__(self)`:
> Iterate over `Token`  objects, from which the annotations can be
> easily accessed. This is the main way of accessing `Token` objects,
> which are the main way annotations are accessed from Python. If faster-
> than-Python speeds are required, you can instead access the annotations
> as a numpy array, or access the underlying C data directly from Cython. [[source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx#L315)]

so based on this you may try:

```
import spacy
from spacy.attrs import ORTH

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
text = "This is some text"
doc = nlp(text)

np_arr = doc.to_array(["ORTH"])
orth = nlp.vocab.strings["is"]
np.where(np_arr == orth)
#(array([1]),)
```

Is it faster?

```
np_array = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100000)
python_list = list(np_array)

def np_where(np_arr,x =10):
    return np.where(np_arr==x)

def list_where(list_, x=10):
    out = []
    for i,item in enumerate(list_):
        if item == x:
            out.append(i)
    return out
```

---

```
%timeit np_where(np_array)
#183 µs ± 4.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit list_where(python_list)
#36.9 ms ± 727 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Note as well, instead of `doc = nlp(text)` you may be interested in `tokens = nlp.tokenizer(text)`

Comment: @marlon Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers